# How to create a progress dialog without title and message?

Tags: android

How to create a progress dialog without title and message?
I used this code:

```
ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "", true);
```

But the progress spin was not centered well in the progress dialog view.

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean it was not centered? Have you tried passing `null` not the empty string. Java is OO.

Comment: ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, null, null, true);  does not help much...  The progressDialog leaves an empty space for the text.

Answer (score 3):

`ProgressDialog` is an extension of `AlertDialog`, so make an `AlertDialog` and set it up manually, with your own graphic in the center to spin away while it's loading.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html